# How do I compile C++/CLI code for Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, silverlight-4.0, c++-cli

I have a C++/CLI library that I would like to use in a Silverlight application. It is supposed to be possible to write code for Silverlight in any .NET language, but so far I've only worked out how to compile C#. Silverlight does not seem to be able to use DLLs compiled for .NET.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and Silverlight 4. The only new projects available for Silverlight are C# projects. Porting the code to C# is not a practical option.

How do I compile C++/CLI code for Silverlight?

Comment: Does your C++/CLI compile with `/clr:safe`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I may have gotten a VS2010 C++/CLI class library project to build with references to (only) Silverlight assemblies.

### Update

Ok, it **is** possible.  But it is not *nice*.

First, you must convince the C++ compiler to NOT load the .NET Framework, using an undocumented compiler switch.  But that's not the worst part.

- Set your C++/CLI project "Common Language Runtime Support" to `/clr:safe`
- Next, under References, remove **all** references.
- Next, in the C++/CLI project properties, under C++ > Command Line, enter `/d1clr:nomscorlib  /FU"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\4.0.50917.0\mscorlib.dll"`
- Now, save the project and exit Visual Studio.  Open the .vcxproj in a text editor, and change the framework version setting.  You want it to be the same as a C# Silverlight project:

  `<TargetFrameworkIdentifier>Silverlight</TargetFrameworkIdentifier>`
  `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>`
  `<SilverlightVersion>$(TargetFrameworkVersion)</SilverlightVersion>`
- Now, reopen Visual Studio, and build the project.  You'll get an error because the compiler auto-generated a file with `#using<mscorlib>` and the search path finds the .NET Framework version first.

  `Silverlight,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cpp(1): fatal error C1197: cannot reference 'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll' as the program has already referenced 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft silverlight\4.0.50917.0\mscorlib.dll'`
- Double-click the error to open the auto-generated file.  Replace the path-less reference with e.g. (here's where you put your references, not in the project properties)

  `#using <c:\program files (x86)\microsoft silverlight\4.0.50917.0\mscorlib.dll>`

  `#using <c:\program files (x86)\microsoft silverlight\4.0.50917.0\System.dll>`

  `#using <c:\program files (x86)\microsoft silverlight\4.0.50917.0\System.Core.dll>`
- Luckily, the compiler leaves your changes in-place.  So you should be good as long as no one cleans your temp directory.
- Building should now succeed.

Then, you need to go add the DLL created by the C++/CLI project to your Silverlight application.  Note that you can't set up a project reference, because VS2010 still isn't convinced that the C++/CLI is a Silverlight project.  So you'll have to browse and add the reference as an assembly file.  (And it won't automatically switch between Debug and Release to match the Silverlight application).

### Final Notes

I got it to run an empty Silverlight application in Debug mode and stop at a breakpoint in the middle of C++/CLI code.  Also the C++/CLI code successfully returned a value to C# and the local variable in C# received the correct value.  So I guess it's working.

I went through a bunch more steps trying to make this work, but I don't think they affected the outcome.  If you run into errors, though, let me know and I'll try to figure out what I omitted from this answer.

Comment: Apparently Visual Web Developer component is needed... I'll be back later (much later).

Comment: The SDK is here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=298170d6-567c-4b90-9917-490ffcddba87&displaylang=en

Comment: I ended up having to do a feature install on VS2010 itself, then add http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b3deb194-ca86-4fb6-a716-b67c2604a139 , then add the Developer Runtime when prompted by VS.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I haven't come across anything else like this in many hours of web searching.

Comment: @richj: Well, I didn't discover that compiler switch myself.  See http://www.opensubscriber.com/message/dotnet-cx@discuss.develop.com/4841793.html  But that thread didn't show how to actually use it, I had to mess with a bunch of different combinations of options to get a successful compile.  And when one file finally compiled, I ran into that issue with the auto-generated file.  Did you get it to work with your code?

Comment: These steps will work for VS2012/.NET 4.5/SL 5. Simply change the paths and .vcxproj attributes as needed. Additionally, 2012 will now allow you to add the CPP DLL as a direct project reference. I had the SL toolkit and VC++ redistributable installed before attempting this. I didn't need to make any installs to get the project built and referenced successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Ben Voigt, thanks for this, it worked for me too.

Also, if your C++ code does anything that is specific to the C++ language (i.e. not entirely IL portable) like using stack semantics for an array, you'll get the following error:

```
could not find assembly 'Microsoft.VisualC.dll' etc.
```

If you recompile with the full .NET Framework and then dump the IL code, you'll find references to "''.$ArrayType$$$BY06$$CB_W modopt" or something similar.  This tells you where to change the code.

I found that after I installed the Silverlight SDK and it got added to "\Program Files(x86)\Reference Assemblies" I did not have to go through all of Ben Voigt's steps, just changing the project file was enough.

Another note, you can also use:

```
<TargetFrameworkProfile>WindowsPhone71</TargetFrameworkProfile>
```

if you want to target Windows Phone (install the SDK first).

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight does not support native C++ libraries, nor any P/Invoke scenarios due to security concerns. If your library is pure .Net you might be able to decompile it with ILDASM and recompile for Silverlight with ILASM.

Comment: Thanks - from what I've read so far, some of the .NET MSIL codes can cause problems on a Silverlight runtime. It might be worth a try - I'll have to check on the unit test coverage for the library.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight is not a powerful development platform like .NET which is tightly integrated with operating system. First of all silverlight is supposed to run on any operating system, so there is no choice of Native API anywhere in silverlight.

Silverlight also does not support MSIL completely, so there is lot of problem in compiling and recomiping it at IL level.

Can you say more about what kind of C++/CLI code you have? Most Rich internet applications (Silverlight's target) do not include any of high powerful computation, instead they are plain simple HTML+JS alternatives. For powerful graphics, you can use Silverlight's PixelShadder support.

[Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)

What you can do alternatively is,
Compile your C++/CLI to regular .NET DLL, use Reflector to disassemble and generate C# source code from your dll, it may not be perfect, but you will have most of your logic converted back in C#.

Comment: The C++/CLI code is pure .NET managed code. It has no user interface or graphics; it's just a straight library with very few dependencies except on system level DLLs that should also be available in Silverlight.

Comment: @richj: By "system level DLLs", you actually mean .NET assemblies which are included with the Silverlight platform?

Comment: @Ben: Yes - assemblies belonging to the Silverlight platform.

Comment: To work in my environment, Reflector would have to translate reliably from C++/CLI to C# in a fully automated build process. I can't port once because the library is under active development. I'll try it if I hit a dead-end with Ben Voigt's method. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able Ben Voigt's solution to work with some minor changes in Visual Studio 2013
Here is what I did different.

- Unload the silverlight project that you want to reference it in. Right click and choose edit project.csproj
- Copy the Target Framework Settings.  For me this was

  > ```
  > <TargetFrameworkIdentifier>Silverlight</TargetFrameworkIdentifier>
  > <TargetFrameworkVersion>v5.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  > <SilverlightVersion>$(TargetFrameworkVersion)</SilverlightVersion>
  > ```
- For the compiler switch `/d1clr:nomscorlib` This was not working for me.  Also a reference to mscorlib for silverlight was automatically added to the complied output without specifying it on the command line options. This is how I got around it.
- Open the project in [Just Deompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx)
- Load the Assembly Editor Plugin
- Navigate the tree to the references
- Delete the reference to the non silverlight mscorlib from the reflexil menu.
- Right click on the top level of the tree for the assembly, and save as under the reflexil menu.

I haven't tested all of the functions, but the ones I have tested so far worked as expected.

Thank you Ben, your post has saved me a lot of time.  I was thinking I was going to have to port my library:)