# Using c++ behind silverlight

Tags: c++, silverlight

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compile C++/CLI code for Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232370/how-do-i-compile-c-cli-code-for-silverlight)

On a silverlight web application I have to use c# or vb code. But i want to use c++ as backend language. Can it be done? if yes how. is there any way to do that.

Comment: i have some code written in c++. i have to use that code behind the web app.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can! in silverlight you can use any language you want but it should not compile to language machine directly instead it should be compile for CLR(Common Language Runtime)

Comment: And how to compile C++ to CLR as it is not part of .NET framework ?

Comment: @Eregrith: The language is called C++/CLI. I assume that's what this answer is talking about.

Comment: Then I think it's a duplicate of [How do I compile C++/CLI code for Silverlight?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232370/how-do-i-compile-c-cli-code-for-silverlight)